# React - export excel with image in cell

Tags: reactjs, excel, image, base64, xlsx

I would like to export a table data to an excel file.
I've got images in my data, and instead of see the url image, i want to have the image in cell.
I doesnt find any library to do it.

do you know one of it ?
Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [exceljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs).

For example, add image to the table:

```
// add image to workbook by filename
const imageId1 = workbook.addImage({
  filename: 'path/to/image.jpg',
  extension: 'jpeg',
});
```